# How to call the single REST api service multiple times parallel at a time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to call a rest api which can respond to N separate calls from different users at the same time ?

Comment: You dont need to worry about this part. IIS take care of it. Just create a API and post data with multiple users, it will work.

Comment: Actually  i need to call a method 100 times parallely  & all the 100 thread  should run in the  background & give response at a time  & it should not run serially.

Comment: Create Tasks using TPL. With each call you can associate a delegate which will do the callback. See Task.Run()

Comment: can  you give any example for that .

Comment: "How to call" asks about how to write client code to asynchronously call a REST API.  But in your body you say "How to build a rest api which can respond" which is asking about how to build the server side REST API to allow response to multiple queries.  This scenario for a client or server are two different things.  You need to clarify with an update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Task DoWorkAsync(string request)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
    { 
        //Send Request Here
    });
}
```

**And Use as** Put in loop

```
DoWorkAsync(request);
```